# NSDictionary store the objects from the last array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I have created 3 buttons at my top.take the offset of them and giving them same `IBAction`.
I want to change images at below according to the which button is pressed.

Further i have to pass these images to the another ViewControler, Here 
i have got 3 arrays named  `bundle1`  ,  `bundle2`  , `bundle3` . in each array i have set of 5 images, in my `Viewdidload` as below,

```
bundle1 = @[@"1.png",@"2.png", @"3.png", @"4.png" ,@"5.png"];

bundle2 = @[@"6.png", @"7.png", @"8.gif",@"9.jpeg", @"10.jpeg" ];

bundle3 = @[@"11.jpg", @"12.jpg" ,@"13.jpeg", @"14.jpeg", @"15.jpeg"];
```

now i had take mutabledictionary, which had upper 3 arrays and i had give them a specific key
as below.

```
mutdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: bundle1 , @"key1" , bundle2 , @"key2" , bundle3 , @"key3" ,nil];
```

Now below is the code  for IBAction of Upper 3 buttons, (Which is the same for all 3 buttons).

```
-(IBAction)morebtn:(id)sender
{
      for (UIView *subview in [scroll  subviews])
    {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
     }

    arraydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([sender tag] == 1) {

    NSLog(@"hey btn1 clicked");

    for (UIImage *b in arraydata)
    {
        [arraydata removeAllObjects];
    }

    arraydata = [mutdict valueForKey:@"key1"];

}



if ([sender tag] == 2) {

    NSLog(@"hey btn2 clicked");
    for (UIImage*b in arraydata)

    {
        [arraydata  removeAllObjects];
    }
   arraydata = [mutdict valueForKey:@"key2"];

}



if ([sender tag] == 3) {

           NSLog(@"hey btn3 clicked");
    for (UIImage*b in arraydata)

    {
        [arraydata removeAllObjects];
    }

    arraydata = [mutdict valueForKey:@"key3"];

}



int x=10,y=300;

for (int k=0; k<arraydata.count; k++) {

    NSLog(@"main called");

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arraydata objectAtIndex:k]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btn.tag=k;

    btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100);

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btn4images1:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    x+=100;

    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width , 200);



    [scroll addSubview:btn];

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

}

}
```

in upper code i trace which button is pressed and according to it i wil give inages in my `NSArray` named `arraydata`.

when i first time click on the all 3 upper buttons they show me image related to their array, but when i second time click on button1 (placed on the top), The images related to button3 are also shown in the Buttonbackground (palced at below part).

so on clicking button1 in below part button background images are overlaped. Seems like my `NSMutableDictionary` stores the data of last array. don't know what exactly happen.

Comment: Why do you have to use a mutable dictioanry? Just curious - it doesn't look like you are mutating the dictionary anyway

Comment: for add data in another array according arrays w.r.t. it`s key.

Comment: You are adding the buttons as subviews to your view. Are you removing them anywhere? Instead of pressing buttons in the order 1->2->3->1. Try 3->1 what is the result?

Comment: @Suhas good point, i dont see a call to remove the subview.

Comment: by clickin 3>1 itz seems no different, whenever i clicking on button 1  ,my button 1 & button3 images seems to overlaped

Comment: i also try this by your suggestion But no result. 
    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        
        NSLog(@"hey btn1 clicked");
      
        for (UIImage*b in arraydata)
        {
         [arraydata removeAllObjects];
         
        }
        
        for (UIButton*b in btnarray){
            [b removeFromSuperview];
        }
        
        [btnarray removeAllObjects];

        arraydata = [mutdict valueForKey:@"key1"];
    
    }

Comment: How are you populating the `btnarray`? Storing all button objects that you create in the for loop?

Comment: yes, I do like,    
       btnarray=  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 
        [btnarray addObject:btn]; btn are buttons created in my for loop.

Comment: If you are keeping this buttonArray, do this in viewDidLoad or something and change images only in your IBAction. Why you creating and add button every time??

Comment: @Anusha: cause i want to change my buttonarray with different background every time dependin on which of my button is pressed.

Comment: You have all references of your buttons in your buttonArray no? So you can access that buttonArray and change its background image in IBAction.

Comment: You have 3 buttons at top with tags 1, 2 and 3. You have another 5 buttons below, in which you display your images according to top 3 buttons. You are keeping references of 5 image buttons in buttonArray. right??

Comment: yes i am adding those buttons in another mutablearray.

Comment: for (UIView *subview in [scroll  subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        
    }                                                             and then,       after gatting tag of the buttons(either 1 ,2 or 3)     i had                                                           scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
        
 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width , 200);
        
        [scroll addSubview:btn];
        
        [self.view addSubview:scroll];
But still images are overlaped.